# Removing page number from a particular page

Tags: page-numbering, templates

Due to a long pseudocode, I want to remove only a particular number in the following latex template.

Is it possible to do it?

**Latex template:** [University of Oxford Mathematical Institute PhD Thesis Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-oxford-mathematical-institute-phd-thesis-template/xzvzjnxbmftm)

**Update:** While the pseudocode takes up the entire page, I added the commande `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of the pseudocode, but the page number was not removed.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , While the pseudocode takes up the entire page, I added the commande `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of the pseudocode, but the page number was not removed.

Comment: as you have provided no example, hard to help. perhaps `\clearpage\pagestyle{empty}...code...\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}`

Comment: This one works. Thanks

Comment: If your pseudocode in a float [p], see the `floatpag` package and `\thisfloatpagestyle`.